# Translation Manager

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation, inline-translations

Is there a nice translation manager which allows admin users to translate CSVs without having to worry about FTP access and if they will mess up the CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub you can find 2 good modules for this and they are [here](https://github.com/barbanet/).
One is for automatic translations with Google Translate and the other has an admin grid to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for. I have made a couple of issues on GitHub as there I have found some issues

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the magento build in "Inline translation" tool?

[image: Enable inline translation from admin]